# Line Not Wrapping In Bash Mac

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I was editing my .bash_profile and set my PS1 to be

`PS1="$(tput setaf 117)Adam$(tput setaf 71)\W  $(tput setaf 228)$ $(tput sgr0)";`

The colors are what I want them to be but as you can see in the picture the name of the directory I'm trying to cd into is overlapping the current line rather than wrapping to a new line. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to wrap with /[ /]
fixed version :

```
PS1="\[$(tput setaf 117)\]Adam/\[$(tput setaf 71)\]\W  \[$(tput setaf 228)\]-> \[$(tput sgr0)\]";ere
```